# error: findEssentialMat was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the function findEssentialMat in OpenCV but I can't compile it.
Below is my sample code. Everytime I perform a make, I got this error:

```
/.../code/test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/.../code/test.cpp:17:51: error: ‘findEssentialMat’ was not declared in this scope
                                         1.0, mask1);
```

Please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've linked necessary lib by using the CMakeLists.txt with **find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )** and **${OpenCV_LIBS}**.

Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat feature1, feature2, mask1;
    Mat E = findEssentialMat(feature1,
                            feature2,
                            1.0,
                            Point2d(0, 0),
                            FM_RANSAC,
                            0.999,
                            1.0, mask1);


    Mat f = findFundamentalMat(feature1, feature2, FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99, mask1);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest development version (3.0.0) ? The function findEssentialMat is not available in the latest released version (2.4.8). If you are using the v3.0.0, you need to verify if the header calib3d.hpp includes the declaration for findEssentialMat.

Comment: Ya, my bad. I just downloaded the OpenCV 3 and now it works. Earlier I was still using OpenCV2.4.8.